# After I added a FireBase to my project this error showed up

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

After I added a FireBase to my project  this error showed up. someone know how to fix it? thank you!

Comment: Try to add `"implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'"` and see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42374426/9060113.

Comment: need to add the this implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:$support_version' and check

Answer (score 0):

Use same version for design and appcompat. as follows

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

here '26.1.0' can be any version you want.
also add    `google()` in project level build.gradle file, as follows

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```